# Word VBA macro fails on one machine but succeeds on others

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA macro in Word that I have been using successfully for a while. All of a sudden, it fails in a very unusual place. The error I am receiving is error 445: Object doesn't support this action. It is happening when I attempt to add a title to a table. It successfully creates a table, and inside the same "With" block where I say `.Title = "CaseTable"`, it successfully changes the `.Style = "Table Grid"`. For whatever reason, it doesn't recognize the ".Title" action for this table. Stepping through the code, this is where it fails. It runs successfully on other machines with the same version of Word.

I tried setting the table title outside of the "With" block by just using `lCaseTable.Title = "CaseTable"`. For transparency, I do have the table variable set successfully and it actually does create a table with the proper column/row count.

```
Sub InsertTable()

Dim doc As Word.Document
Set doc = ThisDocument

Dim lCaseTable As Word.Table
Dim lRange As Word.Range

Set lRange = doc.Content
lRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

Set lCaseTable = doc.Tables.Add(lRange, 2, 6, wdWord8TableBehavior)

With lCaseTable
    .Style = "Table Grid"
    .Title = "CaseTable"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that you have tried.

Comment: This code works fine for me using Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20124) 64-bit. I have stepped through it with no errors and displayed the `.Title` of the table and it is correctly set.

Comment: Try using `Option Explicit` before your subroutine and see if it makes a difference
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement